# forward matched specific location and proxy redirect it in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to forward specific uri if matched to backend in nginx. For example

forward https://www.hostname.com/***/a/b/c** to https://int.hostname.com/***/a/b/c** (Where * is a variable auto populated from regex)

Current configuration looks like below and have no idea how to proceed on above

```
location /a/b/c/ {
    proxy_set_header        Host $proxy_host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_read_timeout      180m;

    proxy_pass http://int.hostname.com/v2/e/t/a/b/c;
    proxy_redirect default;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, in the case where the uri matches "/*/a/b/c" are you sending to the same path on the internal server, or is there some modification? e.g. if someone hits /v1/a/b/c are you just talking to /v1/a/b/c on internal? or is the "/v1" part somehow important

Comment: @JoshuaDeWald It will be same. /v1/a/b/c will be pass to backed as  /v1/a/b/c. Similarly, /sample/v2/a/b/c will be passed as  /sample/v2/a/b/c. * means any path.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want your location to match any URI that ends with `/a/b/c/`, you will need to use regular expression syntax. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The URI suffix of the `proxy_pass` statement is optional. In the absence of a URI suffix, the original URI will be passed unmodified. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ /a/b/c/$ {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://int.hostname.com;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at those docs. You mean I do need to write anything in proxy_pass? Actually, URI may not end with /a/b/c/. Considering this, what should be done if it doesn't end with it?

Comment: You mean that `/a/b/c/` is embedded anywhere inside the URI? In which case, remove the terminating `$`.

Comment: yeah, that's the case and it should also forward exactly same to backend. If URI doesn't content `/a/b/c/` then it shouldn't forward URI to backend.  I hope this works. If there is anything else that I should take care of please let me know. I will test it.